# Fine uploader Bitnami wampstack upload failed

Tags: javascript, php, windows, file-upload, bitnami

I was trying the [Manually Trigger Uploads & Edit File Names](https://fineuploader.com/demos.html#manually-trigger-uploads) Demo to implement on my site and everything works great, but when i tried to upload a file i got the following in the console:

`responseText = {"error":"Server error. Uploads directory isn't writable","uploadName":null}`

I already search other similar questions but none of them seem to work for me, some of the answer talk about a {success : true} but i don't understand what they mean or where is that set, i think is not important because in the demo code there is not success:true property.

I also tried to set the folder permissions where i want to upload the images (which is /project-root/tmp) with this command: `cacls apache2\htdocs\project\tmp /t  /e  /g everyone:f` but that didn't work. The plugin is very good but i think they should put more examples in the documentation. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my template:

```
     <div class="qq-uploader-selector qq-uploader" qq-drop-area-text="Drop files here">
        <div class="qq-total-progress-bar-container-selector qq-total-progress-bar-container">
            <div role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" class="qq-total-progress-bar-selector qq-progress-bar qq-total-progress-bar"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="qq-upload-drop-area-selector qq-upload-drop-area" qq-hide-dropzone>
            <span class="qq-upload-drop-area-text-selector"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="buttons">
            <div class="qq-upload-button-selector qq-upload-button">
                <div>Select files</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <span class="qq-drop-processing-selector qq-drop-processing">
            <span>Processing dropped files...</span>
            <span class="qq-drop-processing-spinner-selector qq-drop-processing-spinner"></span>
        </span>
        <ul class="qq-upload-list-selector qq-upload-list" aria-live="polite" aria-relevant="additions removals">
            <li>
                <div class="qq-progress-bar-container-selector">
                    <div role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" class="qq-progress-bar-selector qq-progress-bar"></div>
                </div>
                <span class="qq-upload-spinner-selector qq-upload-spinner"></span>
                <img class="qq-thumbnail-selector" qq-max-size="100" qq-server-scale>
                <span class="qq-upload-file-selector qq-upload-file"></span>
                <span class="qq-edit-filename-icon-selector qq-edit-filename-icon" aria-label="Edit filename"></span>
                <input class="qq-edit-filename-selector qq-edit-filename" tabindex="0" type="text">
                <span class="qq-upload-size-selector qq-upload-size"></span>
                <button type="button" class="qq-btn qq-upload-cancel-selector qq-upload-cancel">Cancel</button>
                <button type="button" class="qq-btn qq-upload-retry-selector qq-upload-retry">Retry</button>
                <button type="button" class="qq-btn qq-upload-delete-selector qq-upload-delete">Delete</button>
                <span role="status" class="qq-upload-status-text-selector qq-upload-status-text"></span>
            </li>
        </ul>

        <dialog class="qq-alert-dialog-selector">
            <div class="qq-dialog-message-selector"></div>
            <div class="qq-dialog-buttons">
                <button type="button" class="qq-cancel-button-selector">Close</button>
            </div>
        </dialog>

        <dialog class="qq-confirm-dialog-selector">
            <div class="qq-dialog-message-selector"></div>
            <div class="qq-dialog-buttons">
                <button type="button" class="qq-cancel-button-selector">No</button>
                <button type="button" class="qq-ok-button-selector">Yes</button>
            </div>
        </dialog>

        <dialog class="qq-prompt-dialog-selector">
            <div class="qq-dialog-message-selector"></div>
            <input type="text">
            <div class="qq-dialog-buttons">
                <button type="button" class="qq-cancel-button-selector">Cancel</button>
                <button type="button" class="qq-ok-button-selector">Ok</button>
            </div>
        </dialog>
    </div>
```

My Javascript:

```
var manualUploader = new qq.FineUploader({
    element: document.getElementById('fine-uploader-manual-trigger'),
    template: 'qq-template-manual-trigger',
    request: {
        endpoint: ''+ENDPOINT.path+'/endpoint.php'
    },
    autoUpload: true,
    debug: true
});
```

and my endpoint.php (which is almost the same of the [official github](https://github.com/FineUploader/php-traditional-server/blob/master/endpoint.php)):

```
<?php

/**
 * PHP Server-Side Example for Fine Uploader (traditional endpoint handler).
 * Maintained by Widen Enterprises.
 *
 * This example:
 *  - handles chunked and non-chunked requests
 *  - supports the concurrent chunking feature
 *  - assumes all upload requests are multipart encoded
 *  - supports the delete file feature
 *
 * Follow these steps to get up and running with Fine Uploader in a PHP environment:
 *
 * 1. Setup your client-side code, as documented on http://docs.fineuploader.com.
 *
 * 2. Copy this file and handler.php to your server.
 *
 * 3. Ensure your php.ini file contains appropriate values for
 *    max_input_time, upload_max_filesize and post_max_size.
 *
 * 4. Ensure your "chunks" and "files" folders exist and are writable.
 *    "chunks" is only needed if you have enabled the chunking feature client-side.
 *
 * 5. If you have chunking enabled in Fine Uploader, you MUST set a value for the `chunking.success.endpoint` option.
 *    This will be called by Fine Uploader when all chunks for a file have been successfully uploaded, triggering the
 *    PHP server to combine all parts into one file. This is particularly useful for the concurrent chunking feature,
 *    but is now required in all cases if you are making use of this PHP example.
 */

// Include the upload handler class
require_once "handler.php";


$uploader = new UploadHandler();

// Specify the list of valid extensions, ex. array("jpeg", "xml", "bmp")
$uploader->allowedExtensions = array(); // all files types allowed by default

// Specify max file size in bytes.
$uploader->sizeLimit = null;

// Specify the input name set in the javascript.
$uploader->inputName = "qqfile"; // matches Fine Uploader's default inputName value by default

// If you want to use the chunking/resume feature, specify the folder to temporarily save parts.
$uploader->chunksFolder = "chunks";

$method = get_request_method();

// This will retrieve the "intended" request method.  Normally, this is the
// actual method of the request.  Sometimes, though, the intended request method
// must be hidden in the parameters of the request.  For example, when attempting to
// delete a file using a POST request. In that case, "DELETE" will be sent along with
// the request in a "_method" parameter.
function get_request_method() {
    global $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA;

    if(isset($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA)) {
        parse_str($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA, $_POST);
    }

    if (isset($_POST["_method"]) && $_POST["_method"] != null) {
        return $_POST["_method"];
    }

    return $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"];
}

if ($method == "POST") {
    header("Content-Type: text/plain");

    // Assumes you have a chunking.success.endpoint set to point here with a query parameter of "done".
    // For example: /myserver/handlers/endpoint.php?done
    if (isset($_GET["done"])) {
        $result = $uploader->combineChunks("files");
    }
    // Handles upload requests
    else {

        // Call handleUpload() with the name of the folder, relative to PHP's getcwd()
        $result = $uploader->handleUpload("tmp");

        // To return a name used for uploaded file you can use the following line.
        $result["uploadName"] = $uploader->getUploadName();

    }

    echo json_encode($result);
}
// for delete file requests
else if ($method == "DELETE") {
    $result = $uploader->handleDelete("files");
    echo json_encode($result);
}
else {
    header("HTTP/1.0 405 Method Not Allowed");
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the path of the folders:

```
// Call handleUpload() with the name of the folder, relative to PHP's getcwd()
        $result = $uploader->handleUpload("tmp")
```

The comment says that is relative to PHP's getcwd(), but when i echo that function it gets the root project, so at the end the folder path is relative to the location of the endpoint.php file. If you face the same problem as i be careful with the folder paths.

Here is my working endpoint.php:

```
<?php

// Include the upload handler class
require_once "handler.php";


$uploader = new UploadHandler();

// Specify the list of valid extensions, ex. array("jpeg", "xml", "bmp")
$uploader->allowedExtensions = array(); // all files types allowed by default

// Specify max file size in bytes.
$uploader->sizeLimit = null;

// Specify the input name set in the javascript.
$uploader->inputName = "qqfile"; // matches Fine Uploader's default inputName value by default

// If you want to use the chunking/resume feature, specify the folder to temporarily save parts.
$uploader->chunksFolder = "../../uploads";

$method = get_request_method();

// This will retrieve the "intended" request method.  Normally, this is the
// actual method of the request.  Sometimes, though, the intended request method
// must be hidden in the parameters of the request.  For example, when attempting to
// delete a file using a POST request. In that case, "DELETE" will be sent along with
// the request in a "_method" parameter.
function get_request_method() {
    global $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA;

    if(isset($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA)) {
        parse_str($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA, $_POST);
    }

    if (isset($_POST["_method"]) && $_POST["_method"] != null) {
        return $_POST["_method"];
    }

    return $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"];
}

if ($method == "POST") {
    header("Content-Type: text/plain");

    // Assumes you have a chunking.success.endpoint set to point here with a query parameter of "done".
    // For example: /myserver/handlers/endpoint.php?done
    if (isset($_GET["done"])) {
        $result = $uploader->combineChunks("../../uploads");
    }
    // Handles upload requests
    else {

        // Call handleUpload() with the name of the folder, relative to PHP's getcwd()
        $result = $uploader->handleUpload("../../uploads"); //this folder was created in the root project, at the same level as wp-content

        // To return a name used for uploaded file you can use the following line.
        $result["uploadName"] = $uploader->getUploadName();

    }

    echo json_encode($result);
}
// for delete file requests
else if ($method == "DELETE") {
    $result = $uploader->handleDelete("../../uploads");
    echo json_encode($result);
}
else {
    header("HTTP/1.0 405 Method Not Allowed");
}

?>
```